# editable content html email

Tags: html, html-parsing, email, html-email

I have a basic html email template as

```
<table width="100%">
    <tr>
        <td>
            <table width="780" border="1" height="600" bgcolor="olive" align="center">
                <tr>
                    <td valign="top">
                        <table border="1" width="780" bgcolor="white" style="text-align: center; min-height:20px; height: auto;">
                            <tr>
                                <td>
                                    <p style="font-color:#ffffff;">Banner heading goes here
                                    <br />
                                    Sed lacus. Donec lectus. Nullam pretium nibh ut turpis. Nam bibendum. In nulla tortor, elementum vel, tempor at, varius non, purus. Mauris vitae nisl nec metus placerat consectetuer. Donec ipsum. Proin imperdiet est. Phasellus dapibus semper urna. Pellentesque ornare, orci in consectetuer hendrerit, urna elit eleifend nunc, ut consectetuer nisl felis ac diam. Etiam non felis. Donec ut ante. In id eros. Suspendisse lacus turpis, cursus egestas at sem. Mauris quam enim, molestie in, rhoncus ut, lobortis a, est.
                                    </p>
                                </td>
                            </tr>
                        </table>
                    </td>
                </tr>
            </table>
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

How do I make the Banner heading area as editable in the email?  I am using magnet mail. -

Comment: You make it a textbox or a textarea prehaps. But that's what you do not want right?

Answer (score 2):

With a HTML email you cannot do this.

Comment: It is possible using the email services like magnet mail, constant contact etc. I just don't know what is the tag for the editable area